# Chrome extension: Content script matching URL pattern for Gmail message

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail

For my Chrome extension, I need a matching pattern for any valid Gmail message URL. Example:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox/140acd877b64109b`

What I tried in `manifest.json` is the following:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
        "matches":      ["*://*.mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox/*"],
        "css":          ["default.css"]
    } ]
```

However, my custom stylesheet is not applied when I access a Gmail message with the URL pattern above.

Any ideas why it is not applied?

If I only use `"matches":      ["*://*.mail.google.com"]`, then it works. Yet I do not want the stylesheet to be applied to my inbox page too. Thus I am looking for a pattern to only catch single message pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location fragment (`#...`) is *always* ignored in the match pattern. [Last time I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058263/css-injection-fails-using-declaration-in-content-scripts-but-works-when-loaded/17459723#17459723), the query string is also ignored for the `"css"` field.

To get the desired effect, just insert the stylesheet on `"*://*.mail.google.com/*"`, and use a content script to detect URL changes. For example:

Fragment of `manifest.json`:

```js
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches":      ["*://*.mail.google.com/*"],
    "css":          ["default.css"],
    "js":           ["style-toggler.js"]
} ]
```

Example of `default.css`:

```js
.turn-on-my-style img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

If prefixing your CSS selectors takes too much efforts, I suggest to use a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

`style-toggler.js`:

```js
function hashCheck() {
    if (/^#inbox\/.*/.test(location.hash)) {
        document.documentElement.classList.add('turn-on-my-style');
    } else {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove('turn-on-my-style');
    }
}
window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashCheck);
hashCheck();
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. But I do not completely understand the content of the stylesheet. In my extension, I want to add a `margin-top` property to an existing class `.aeH` but as mentioned above, only if I am not in the inbox. As far as I understand your example, it adds or removes a new class, but does not modify the property of an existing class.

Comment: @orschiro Prefix every selector of your original style sheet with the custom class name (`.turn-on-my-style`, in my example). Then, you can effectively toggle the styles by adding or removing the class name from the ancestor element (the root element, `<html>`, `document.documentElement` in my example).

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. It is working great! Thanks. In `default.css` I added `.toggleClass .aeH {
    margin-top: 55px !important;
}` and in `default.js` I added `classList.add('toggleClass');`