# Correct match pattern for my URL using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and i want to know the correct match pattern for my URL so that I can execute some javascript

I want it to execute if my url ends in #test

> ex. https://blah.com/blah1/blah2/blah3/blah4#test

So it can be any URL as long as it ends in #test.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do pattern matching for chrome extensions on the hash of a url. See [Chrome extension: Content script matching URL pattern for Gmail message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419481/chrome-extension-content-script-matching-url-pattern-for-gmail-message). But what you can do is check the document.location.hash property for the term you are looking for and only execute your script there. Then you can have a broader pattern match for the site but only execute the functionality of the site when required.

NB If it's a hard requirement that it has to end with #test then you can simplify things by adding an endsWith function.

Something like:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};

if(document.location.hash.endsWith("#test")){ /* do stuff */ }
```

endsWith taken from [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript)